# WPF MahApp.Metro, Change border color of UI controls globally

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using [Mahapps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) in my Application.
I created a *Custom Accent Resource Dictionary* [according to [this tutorial]](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html) and every things work well but i can't **change Border Color of elements globally** in my application.

I added following custom resource (`BorderBrush`) to my *custom accent resource dictionary* but it can't change anythings:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    ............... OTHER RESOURCES ..............

    <Color x:Key="BorderColor">#666</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource BorderColor}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

For example i want change Border Color of all Buttons...

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit from the base styles and make your changes.

Samles

```
<Color x:Key="CustomBorderColor">#666</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource CustomBorderColor}"/>

<Style x:Key="CustomMetroCircleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CustomBorderBrush}" />
</Style>

<!-- or -->

<Style x:Key="CustomMetroButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CustomBorderBrush}" />
</Style>

<!-- or -->

<Style x:Key="CustomToggleButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButton}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CustomBorderBrush}" />
</Style>

<!-- usage -->

<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{DynamicResource CustomMetroCircleButtonStyle}" />
<!-- or -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{DynamicResource CustomMetroButton}" />
<!-- or -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{DynamicResource CustomToggleButton}" />
```

etc...

Hope that helps!